# How to convert a Date from typescript into c# and back with the correct time zone?

Tags: c#, typescript, timezone

I'm using angularx-flatpickr for selecting a date with time.
My local timezone is +2.

I'm selecting this date: **'10.07.2019 12:00'**
In JS console i'm getting: **Wed Jul 10 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)**
In the api post i see JSON object with time=**2019-07-10T10:00:00.000Z**
In c# i'm using System.DateTime and i get a DateTime object with: **{10.07.2019 10:00:00}**
In datebase stored: **10.07.2019 10:00:00**
Back in JS when requesting the data i use a view model with Date type. But the object from the view model is a string **"2019-07-10T10:00:00"**.
So now i can use **new Date("2019-07-10T10:00:00")** to convert into JS Date. But the time is now wrong because of the time zone: **Wed Jul 10 2019 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)**

I think it makes sense to store the UTC DateTime in the datebase.
So this means i need to convert the time in JS to the correct time zone from the user. What is the best best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more helpful to add code to your question [so we can see how your code is working end-to-end](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  However, I think from your description I can spot the problem:

> Back in JS when requesting the data i use a view model with Date type. But the object from the view model is a string `"2019-07-10T10:00:00"`.

Somewhere in your code you are loading the value from the database back into a `DateTime` object.  For example, if you are using a `DataReader` to load your data, you might be doing something like this:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) someDataReader["@TheDateTimeDBField"];
```

When doing so, the resulting value will have its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  This later causes the serialization to not include any offset information.

Your code doesn't have any information to tell it that the values in your database are in UTC.  With `DateTime` values, you must do that explicitly after loading:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) someDataReader["@TheDateTimeDBField"];
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

This will set the `Kind` property to `DateTimeKind.Utc`, which will later serialize with the `Z` appended. (This works because JSON.Net's default date format includes [the `K` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier)).

Alternatively, consider using `DateTimeOffset` values, both in your .NET code, and in your database (assuming MS SQL Server).  Then the values will be stored and serialized with the offset included.  It will use `+00:00` instead of `Z`, but will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that almost all correct in your approach. The error arises on the step when you get date from DB and send it to JS in string format. The date you sent is **"2019-07-10T10:00:00"**. And it denotes date in local timezone as it lacks symbol **Z** at the end. So add **Z** symbol to the end and you'll get date in UTC timezone. So line

```
new Date("2019-07-10T10:00:00Z")
```

will result in time **Wed Jul 10 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)**

I recommend to add **Z** on C# side, so date transmitted to JS in correct format.

Details about date formats in JS [can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_date_formats.asp).